# display the retrieved content after choose the option from drop down list in different places using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a table which has a dynamic content.
the table contains a drop down list, where the user needs to choose an option then the displayed data will be returned using ajax.
currently it's work BUT the problem is that it's working only with the first row.
After l choose from the drop down list in the second row  the result was displayed on 
the first row :"/ !!

table code

```
<table class="bordered" >
<tr class="bordered">

<?php
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM  `order` ");
    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    $qry1="SELECT * 
FROM  `order` ";
    $result=mysql_query($qry1);
    if(mysql_num_rows($qry)>0){
?>
<th>delete</th><th>edit</th><th>staff info</th><th>staff</th><th>ex</th><th>phone</th><th>name</th><th>id</th><th>quantity</th><th>status</th><th>time</th><th>date</th><th>order number</th><th></th>
</tr>
    <?php
            while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            { 
            $idem = $info['emp_id'];
            $q="select * from empoyee where emp_id= '".$idem."';";
            $r=mysql_query($q);
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td>
            <form method="POST" action="delete_asu.php">
            <input type="image" src="delete1.png" width="25%" height="20%"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="<?php echo $info['order_num']; ?>" />
            </form></td>
            <td>
            <?php $id=$info['order_num']; 
            echo '<form method="POST" action="update_asu_form.php?id='.$id.'">' ?>
            <input type="image" src="settings-24-128.png" width="20%" height="15%"/>
            </form></td>
            <td id="txtHint"></td>
            <td>

                <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                <option></option>
                <?php

                $sql=mysql_query("SELECT asu_name from asu_staff");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                echo "<option>" .$row["asu_name"]. "</option>";
                }

                ?>
                </select>

            </td>
            <?php 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $r )) 
            {
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $row['ex']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['emp_name']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?></td>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $info['quantity']; ?></td><td><?php echo $info['status']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $info['time']; ?></td><td><?php echo $info['date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $info['order_num']; ?></td><td><input type="radio" name="choose" value="<?php echo $info['order_num']; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            } 
        }
        else echo "<h1>no orders</h1>";
        ?>

</table>
```

The ajax code

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

The php code

```
 $q=$_GET["q"];
            $sql="SELECT * FROM asu_staff WHERE asu_name = '".$q."'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr> <td>" . $row['asu_id'] . " </td><td>staff id</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr> <td>" . $row['phone'] . " </td><td>staff phone</td></tr>";
            echo "</table>";
```

**Yaaah It's work**

the idea:

Alhamdullilallah it's working perfectly now :D
the problem was from the id of the  where I retrieve the content 
I make an incremental id and send it to the ajax , then it's work

Answer (score 0):

The value that is given by the select is what is in the value="" attribute on each option. In your case you need to change the code displaying the options to:

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
 <option value="" selected></option>
<?php
   $sql=mysql_query("SELECT asu_name from asu_staff");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
     echo "<option value=\"".$row["asu_name"]."\">" .$row["asu_name"]. "</option>";
   }

?>
</select>
```

Try this.

p.s. you could select an id with the name in your query, then use the id in the value="" attribute. Your query in your php code could then use the id in stead of the name.

Comment: thank you for your fast response : ) , but actually this is not my problem the problem is when I choose the option from the drop down list of the second row the content displayed on the first row. my main problem not the returned data but the display of the second row data it's work perfect with the first row only :(

Comment: I haven't checked the behaviour of a select input where the optionn tags don't have value="" attributes but I would have thought they might always return the first value.

Comment: Also, you might want to pass "this" instead of "this.value" then check the value attribute in the javascript function. It may even be that you need to use "this.options[this.selectedIndex].value".

Comment: actually it's work with me with out the value because the code is retrieve the content of the option. thank very much Arthur it's working now the problem was from the <td id=""> I make the id incremental then it's work :D , the id value = to the row number I get the row number by making an incremental value inside the while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
            {